# How are the eigenvalues of $M$ related to $f_{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$\begin{bmatrix}f_{n+1}\\ f_{n}\end{bmatrix} = \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}2 - \frac{\omega}{K} & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}}_{M}\begin{bmatrix}f_{n} \\ f_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}$

Fix $K$. Suppose $\frac{\omega}{K} < 0 $.

**Q.** What do the eigenvalues of $M$ tell me about the grid functions $f_n := f(x_n), \; n \in \mathbb{Z}$

**Attempt:**

Computing the eigenvalues:

$\begin{align}\alpha_{1,2} &= 1 - \frac{1}{2}\frac{\omega}{K} \pm \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(\frac{\omega}{K})^{2} - 4\frac{\omega}{K}}\tag{1}\\
&= 1-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\omega}{K}\pm \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\left (\frac{\omega}{K} -4 \right )\frac{\omega}{K}}\tag{2}\end{align}$

Suppose the discriminant is to be non-negative. Then we require $(\frac{\omega}{K} - 4)\underbrace{\frac{\omega}{K}}_{<0} \geq 0$

So we need $\frac{\omega}{K} - 4 \leq 0 \implies \frac{\omega}{K} \leq 4$.

Comment: $f_n=c_1\alpha_1^n+c_2\alpha_2^n$?

Comment: @BobDobbs Can you explain as an Answer how you arrive to that?

Comment: diagonalize the matrix, and compute its nth power

Comment: @Koobe Can you prove? I know by heart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=2-\frac{\omega}{k}$, then $a>2$. The characteristic polynomial is given by
$$ x^2-ax+1=0
$$
So $2\alpha_1=a+\sqrt{a^{2}-4}, 2\alpha_2=(a-\sqrt{a^2-4})$. Compute out the eigenvectors for $\alpha_i$ by $Ax=\alpha_1x$, $Ay=\alpha_2 y.$ We can get

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
a & 1 \\
-1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix}
x & y 
\end{bmatrix}   \begin{bmatrix}
\alpha_1 & 0 \\
0 & \alpha_2 
\end{bmatrix}   \begin{bmatrix}
x & y 
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}  $$
Therefore,
$$  \begin{bmatrix}
f_n \\
f_{n-1} 
\end{bmatrix}  =\begin{bmatrix}
x & y 
\end{bmatrix}   \begin{bmatrix}
\alpha_1 & 0 \\
0 & \alpha_2 
\end{bmatrix}^{n-1}   \begin{bmatrix}
x & y 
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}  \begin{bmatrix}
f_1 \\
f_0 
\end{bmatrix}  
$$